# Multi-threading molecular simulations in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am developing a molecular dynamics simulation code in C++, which essentially takes atom positions and other properties as input and simulates their motion under Newton's laws of motion. The core algorithm uses what's called the Velocity Verlet scheme and looks like:

```
//  iterate through time (k=[1,#steps])
double Dt = 0.002; // time step
double Ttot = 1.0; // total time
double halfDt = Dt/2.0;

for (int k = 1; k*Dt <= Ttot; k++){
    for (int i = 0; i < number_particles; i++)
        vHalf[i] = p[i].velocity + F[i]*halfDt; // step 1

    for (int i = 0; i < number_particles; i++)
        p[i].position += vHalf[i]*Dt; // step 2

    for (int i = 0; i < number_particles; i++)
        F[i] = Force(p,i); // recalculate force on all particle i's

    for (int i = 0; i < number_particles; i++)
        p[i].velocity = vHalf[i] + F[i]*halfDt; // step 3
}
```

Where `p` is an array of class objects which store things like particle position, velocity, mass, etc. and `Force` is a function that calculates the net force on a particle using something like Lennard-Jones potential.

My question regards the time required to complete the calculation; all of my subroutines are optimized in terms of crunching numbers (e.g. using `x*x*x` to raise to the third power instead of `pow(x,3)`), but the main issue is the time loop will often be performed for millions of iterations and there are typically close to a million particles. Is there any way to implement this algorithm using multi-threading? From my understanding, multi-threading essentially opens another stream of data to and from a CPU core, which would allow me to run two different simulations at the same time; I would like to use multi-threading to make just one of these simulations run faster

Comment: A thread of execution is the flow of execution of your program. When you have 1 thread, there is 1 point in your code where the program is at a given time, which function or expression it's currently evaluating. With multithreading you have multiple points, each running at the same time. Code that was not designed for multithreading cannot be easily made safe to use with multithreading. It's not something you can just turn on. You need to transform your code and it is very hard to not introduce subtle changes or errors when doing it.

Comment: Multthreading particle simulations is generally pretty easy. You use double buffered data & partition the processing of all your particles into N groups where N is the number of threads.

Comment: I suppose you need the complete result of the current time step before you can start with the next time step. That alone already suggests that you wont get the best benefit from using more threads. Consider to reformulate the time step as a matrix multiplication, then look for parallel matrix multiplaction algorithms, there should be plenty

Comment: Re, "multi-threading...opens another stream of data..." No. That's not right at all. Have you ever tried to understand a program by thinking about how _the computer_ executes the program statements, one-by-one?  OK, now erase "the computer" from your mind and start saying, "a thread" instead. A _thread_ is an entity in the operating system that executes your code, and in a multi-threaded program, you've got more than one thread, all executing side-by-side, possibly executing different parts of your program... or not, in the same shared address space.

Comment: @SolomonSlow "executing the program statements, one-by-one" is strictly speaking wrong also for a single thread. First because modern cpus dont execute instructions one-by-one and also because the cpu does not get to execute the program statements written in code, but what the compiler produces out of them. Though I am splitting hairs ;)

Comment: It's worth noting you may get better performance by seeking other optimizations first such as SIMD support or using better math libraries. But as with all things performance, profile before making any changes.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux if I'm following your explanation of multithreading acting as multiple points in my program, then I could have, say, four points total, one for each ```i``` loop. Then once each of these loops finishes, I can increment my ```k``` loop, and have each point rotate to the next ```i``` loop?

Comment: @ChaseRLewis does this double-buffering significantly increase memory pr required computing power? I only ask because I would like to just use my local machine but take full advantage of its computing power (currently, my algorithm only uses around 15% of my CPU and 20% memory)

Comment: @idclev463035818, You're not so much splitting hairs as, you are looking at the wrong level of abstraction. A programmer _must_ be able to understand what the program is going to do by looking at the program's source code. Whatever transformations the compiler and the hardware perform on the programmer's instructions, the end result of a single thread executing a sequence of hardware instructions must ultimately be the same as if the source level statements were executed in program order.  If not, then the language and/or its implementation would be useless.

Comment: @SolomonSlow nicely worded, point taken. I can only agree to what you say

Comment: @Mgetz how would these math libraries improve performance? I use the basic multiplication and addition operators as much as possible and only use functions like ```sqrt``` when I can't avoid doing so, I thought this was as efficient as I could get EDIT: I see the benefit of SIMD, native parallel execution

Comment: @Iratium Double buffered memory doubles your memory requirements but it guarantees your calculation doesn't get altered while processing the current state. It is how almost ALL GPU programming is done which is highly parallel. The speed of the calculation generally with scale linearly based on the number of cores until you saturate your memory bus.

Comment: @Iratium math libraries like Intel's MKL etc are highly platform optimized, that means you can use the higher order methods to make your code readable while taking advantage of things like AVX2/AVX512 where appropriate. It's also worth noting that some of these libraries can even use the GPU for doing the math. That can (if the data set is large enough) be much more efficient.

Comment: Speedup for many-particle simulation is commonly/traditionally achieved by using a cutoff to zero for the force (and modifications to keep it smooth and halfways Hamiltonian) and binning/clustering. Make a grid with a mesh-width about the cutoff radius and assign the particles to cells. Then you only need to take interactions of particles of neighboring cells into account. This is then naturally parallelizable, one task per cell.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP).

Your specific use case is trivially parallelizable.
Prallelization should be as simple as:

```
double Dt = 0.002; // time step
double Ttot = 1.0; // total time
double halfDt = Dt/2.0;

for (int k = 1; k*Dt <= Ttot; k++){

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < number_particles; i++)
        vHalf[i] = p[i].velocity + F[i]*halfDt; // step 1
        p[i].position += vHalf[i]*Dt; // step 2

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < number_particles; i++)
        F[i] = Force(p,i); // recalculate force on all particle i's    
        p[i].velocity = vHalf[i] + F[i]*halfDt; // step 3
}
```

Most popular compilers and platforms have support for OpenMP.

Comment: `number_particles` should be large enough to justify the thread synchronization overhead. Otherwise your speedup can be `< 1`

Comment: this is originally what I thought multi-threading could do, namely dedicating one core to each of the ```i``` for loops. The reason why I posted the question is this algorithm needs to perform each loop sequentially at each time step; would the method you proposed still work for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @Iratium this doesn't run each for in a different thread. This splits each for into N partitions and runs each partition in a different core. Then locks at the end of the for until all partitions are completed. It does what you need.